# `size` returning strange values

Tags: ruby

If I do `2.size`, why do I get `8` as output? Shouldn't it throw an error?

`2.length` throws the error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for 2:Fixnum

`2.count`

> NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for 2:Fixnum

Is `2.size` counting bits?

`0xFFF0000.size` returns `8` as well.

`11111111111111111111.size` is `8`, whereas `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.size` is `32`.

May be it is counting bits after all.

Comment: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 is significantly larger than what can fit into 32 bits (4,294,967,295 unsigned).

Comment: Obviously, the first thing to is read the doc for [Fixnum#size](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-size). It's seems pretty clear to me. What didn't you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just [returns the number of bytes used for the internal representation of the number](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-size).

The reason you get 32 for bigger numbers is that Ruby will automatically create `Bignums` instead of `Fixnum` if the number is too big.

```
foo = 1111111111111111111
bar = 11111111111111111111
baz = 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
foo.class # => Fixnum
foo.size  # => 8
bar.class # => Bignum
bar.size  # => 8
baz.class # => Bignum
baz.size  # => 63
```